# OSError [Errno 99] - python

Tags: python, socketserver

i want to execute the following simple server code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 22331                # Reserve a port
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print('Got connection from', addr)
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()
```

gives the following error while executing:

```
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

why the OS cannot bind the specified port with the address?

Comment: You probably want `host = '0.0.0.0'`. `socket.gethostname()` returns the hostname, not an IP address.

Comment: I agree with @ValentinLorentz, you should try to be specific about the IP or use `0.0.0.0`. It looks like your `gethostname()` returns an IP / name that doesn't resolve to an IP address present on the host you're executing the script from.

Comment: The code you mentioned in your question is not generating this error. It worked fine on Windows 8 with python v2.7. Please show us the client side code too!

Comment: @ValentinLorentz should it be host=IPAddress rather than host name in order to be bound?

Comment: @ρss i didn't run the client yet, because the server is not running/ listening.

Comment: @maria simply try this `host = '0.0.0.0'` and see what happens?

Comment: how does using hostname or 0.0.0.0 matter?

Comment: it works with giving the IP address, but not with host name

Comment: @maria As I mentioned before your code works fine for me even if you give a hostname or an IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works using the ip address but not using hostname.

You should have something like this in your `/etc/hosts` mapping   ip  to  hostname.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   your_hostname_here

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Your `/etc/hostname` should obviously be the same as above.

Reboot and you should be able to ping your hostname successfully.

You can also use `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` to get the i.p as opposed to the hostname

Comment: As a side note: it might take a minute or so for the port to be available after killing the process.

Comment: Nope, this specific error is usually `[Errno 48] Address already in use`

Comment: i have checked and this port is not in use

Comment: what happens when you ping your hostname?

Comment: 100% packet loss, my hostname is resolved to my network public address, i can ping my private IP address but not the public

Comment: @maria what is in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname?

Comment: the /etc/hosts only shows the loopback address and somelines for IPv6 and /etc/hostname shows the name of my computer (cs)

Comment: ok I will edit my answer to avoid having a lot of comments. you need to  add details to etc/hosts

Comment: tnx, it is fixed, the problem was with the hosts file, i have changed the host name but didn't edited the file, so it was showing something rather than my host name, now i added the host name and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try set the `SO_REUSEADDR` option to the socket:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```