# graphlab.SFrame.show() Error: Requested port is unavailable: None

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook, port, graphlab, sframe

upon entering the command:

```
graphlab.show();
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Requested port is unavailable: None
```

So, I tried to set the port by typing:

```
gl.canvas.set_target('ipynb', 8888).
```

But not fruitful. I checked the open ports in ubuntu terminal and assigned it different points (among some confirmed open ports) but it's not working anyways.

I am using python jupyter notebook in browser through pycharm.

Answer (score 3):

Try downgrading tornado:

```
pip install tornado==4.5.3
```

(replace `pip` with `conda` if you are using Anaconda)

Using

```
gl.canvas.set_target('ipynb')
```

without setting a port should then be enough.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090119/jupyter-notebook-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-io-l)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of  [OSError [Errno 99] - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843165/oserror-errno-99-python) applies here also.

If it works using the ip address but not using hostname.

Removing double localhost in `/etc/hosts` should be solution. hosts file should look something like this (mapping   ip  to  hostname)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   your_hostname_here

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```